# How to precompile Ember Handlebars templates from command line?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to precompile Handlebars templates from Windows command line. Normal Handlebars templates can be compiled by using command: "handlebars  -f ". But this doesn't work for Ember Handlebars templates.

PS. I'm not using grunt, broccoli, rake etc as they are too slow on Windows. I have my own custom solution for building stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [this Node package](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/node-ember-precompile) to compile Ember templates without a build tool. It's pretty simple to use:

```
ember-precompile index.hbs -f index.js
```

Comment: Yep, that is what I use.